# new content element at content wizard

Tags: typo3

I have some problems with typo 7.6.2

I would like to add my own content elements to the content-element wizard.

My own extension with templates, partials, TypoScript... worked and the element is visible in the content-element wizard.

[Content-element Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOugK.jpg)

If I choose the new element and click the place to add the following [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEJfc.jpg) is shown.

(ext_tables.php):

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Configuration/TypoScript',
    'Template Extension'
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('
mod {
wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.extra {
    header = KCW Inhalte
    elements {
        mitglied {
            icon = ../typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/content/content-header.svg
            title = Mitglied
            description = Ein Mitglied anlegen
            tt_content_defValues {
                CType = mitglied
            }
        }
    }
    show = *
   }
  }
');
```

"Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php":

```
$TCA['mitglied'] = array(

    'columns' => array(
        'name' => array (       
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Vorname Name',
            'config'  => array (
                'type'    => 'input',
                'size' => '20'
            )
        ),

        'spitzname' => array (      
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Spitzname',
            'config'  => array (
                'type'    => 'input',
                'size' => '20'
            )
        ),

        'geburtstag' => array (     
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Geburtstag',
            'config'  => array (
                'type'    => 'input',
                'size' => '10',
                'eval' => 'date',
            )
        ),

        'posten' => array (     
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Posten',
            'config'  => array (
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'items' => array (
                        array('Mitglied'),
                        array('Präsident'),
                        array('Kassenwart'),
                        array('Vergnügungsausschuss'),
                ),
                'size' => 1,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            )
        ),

        'foto' => array (       
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label'   => 'Foto',
            'config' => array(
                    'type' => 'group',
                    'internal_type' => 'file',
                    'allowed' => 'jpg',
                    'max_size' => 1000,
                    'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/pics/',
                    'show_thumbs' => 1,
                    'size' => 3,
                    'minitems' => 1,
                    'maxitems' => 1,
                    'autoSizeMax' => 10,
            )
        ),
    ),
    'types' => array(
             '0' => array('showitem' => 'name,spitzname,geburtstag,posten,foto')
    )
);

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility::mergeRecursiveWithOverrule($GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content'], $tcaTtContent);
```

I think the problem is located in these lines in ext_tables.php:

```
   tt_content_defValues {
      CType = mitglied
   }
```

Comment: This is English language forum, please translate your question

Comment: I already have checked the post at creativeworkspace.de but I think that is not the same syntax like the [TCAReference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/). But it's possible that I'm too stupid for that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the value `mitglied` as value of the field `cType`. The `tt_content_devValues` just sets the default values for the newly created content element.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.cType.addItems.mitglied = Field title
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html#pagetceformconfobj